# Django middleware to rewrite a request?

Tags: django, url-routing

I would like to write middleware (or some other method) for re-writing a request (AFAICT the contents of `request.META['PATH_INFO']`) before the URL resolver. This is so I could pick it up as a component of the URL and treat it as another view argument.

Something like this:

```
def process_request(self, request):
    request.META['PATH_INFO'] = "string to prefix/" + request.META['PATH_INFO']
```

But it looks like the URL resolver is getting in there first.

Is there any way to achieve this?

My middleware is installed as the first in the list.

EDIT: To clarify, I want to re-write this request:

`http://something.com/my/view/` => `/something.com/my/view`
`http://somethingelse.com/my/view/` => `/somethingelse.com/my/view`
etc in middleware before the url handler.

I am currently doing it with view decorators which modify the kwargs passed to the view funciton, but it doesn't quite feel right.

---

Why? My app is handling requests from multiple domains and I would like a way to deduce the domain in middleware and have it passed in as a view argument.

Comment: I'm confused. Are the multiple domains redirecting all to one domain or can you literally browse the same site while keeping different domain names in the address bar? If it's redirecting, Django will never know the original domain name, so you're out of luck. If the different domain names stay in the address bar, you can get the host from request.META in your view.

Comment: No, it's not redirecting. The server is accepting connections on a number of domains and passing the request straight to Django. The problem isn't detecting the domain, the problem is finding a sensible to way to integrate this with the url handler in a way that allows me to reverse URLs in the least hacky manner possible.

Comment: `reverse` returns relative URLs. It shouldn't matter what the domain is, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I want to return complete absolute URLs complete with the domain (which I would like to pass in). Currently solving the problem with a combination of view decorators to handle the incoming requests, and a custom `reverse` function which wraps django.core.urlresolvers.reverse. But it would be nice to integrate it at a lower level.

Comment: have you tried putting it last? middleware runs from top to bottom as you specify in the settings file. If you put lit last, then it will be the last one that modifies the request object

Comment: Surely the sooner the better? I get the impression that all the middleware runs in a block, either before or after the URL resolver. So why would it help to have it run last?

Answer (score 0):

If you use wsgi, I think you can do the rewrite in the .wsgi script (that is before the request is given to django)